# controlling text overflow in html5 input field

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML5 input field that displays a clear button with an "x" in it in webkit browsers when the field has characters in it. The problem is that, when the field is filled with characters, these will run behind the x button until they reach the right side of the input before they are scrolled off of the left side of the input.

I want to define the width of the input area in which characters may appear. How is this done in the most cross-browser way possible? (I don't need the x buttons in all browsers, but I don't mind them when they do show up. I just need to define the area an input has available to visible characters so they start to scroll off to the left before they get behind the x buttons)

Comment: Show us the code that you have already.  Much easier to give advice that way :)

Comment: Are you, by any chance, talking about [search inputs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.search.html)? I'm asking because of the `x` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using padding-right CSS property

```
<input type="text" style="padding-right: 1em; width: 5em;">
```

Comment: While simulating an input with a div would work, this is the simplest solution I've seen. Make sure width is set somewhere, then set padding-right. Works like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: i agree, but this way you have to position the image absolute and on top of the input. not the best solutions imho but it sure works very well

Comment: @mercsen - I think you are misunderstanding the question. The "clear" image is created automatically by the browser not the developer, there is no absolute positioning of anything. Also, even if you DID want to put your own image you could use a background image and background position/attach, so there still wouldn't be any need for absolute positioning.

Comment: @LastCoder haha yeah i totally did. i thought "that displays a clear button" is user created not by the browser itself ;)

Answer (score 1):

Its simple!

http://jsfiddle.net/neRWQ/1/

just "hide" the input and simulate one with an div. So you have a bit space on the right where the user cant write ;)

`<div class="input_container"><input type="TEXT" /></div>`

```
input {
background-color: white;
border: 0px;
width: 180px;
outline: 0px;
}
.input_container {
width: 200px;
border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Comment: with some JS or clever CSS its also possible to get back the orange outline border for the div but i dont want to spoil the fun ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about [search inputs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.search.html) (which hare the only ones that have a small `x` displayed in WebKit browsers that I can think of), I'd recommend removing the custom styling that causes more trouble than anything else:

```
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
    display: none;
}
```